# Rude behaviour by HRBP during onboarding, should I quit now?

Tags: work-environment, human-resources, onboarding

I haven't completed the first day at my new job. We had an onboarding call where the HRBP (**Human Resource Business Partner**) was very rude to me. My intuition says that I will be treated the same way throughout the job. I have not yet finished my onboarding formalities, should I quit now?

Comment: What's an HRBP?

Comment: Human resource business partner, it's similar to HR

Comment: Only you can make that decision. Seems strange to quit a job over a single person being rude on a phone call. Any company will have their share of rude people, simply because they *exist*.

Comment: That's correct, however, she is responsible for all the hr tasks of the team I will be joining. I fear this will make my life tough

Comment: What do you consider rude?

Comment: It would help if you were specific and detailed about "rude behavior".  What you consider rude might be normal for others.  Also, will you be working/interacting with this HRBP on a regular basis?  I'm at my present company for over 4 years now and have never encountered the HR person since my first day.  So unless you have another job lined up or can go back to your old position (both seem unlikely) you should at least give it a try.  In many companies HR is staffed by contractors.  Could just be a bad one.

Answer (score 5):

You should absolutely not quit now, that's ridiculous. There is one person who you perceived as rude (which doesn't mean necessarily they *were* rude), and that is quite irrelevant to your job 99.9% of the time. You will run into lots of people including your future colleagues who have problems with people they don't know, and after a week or two of knowing you they are the best colleagues to have.

There is a reason why you have three months of probation and not one day.

I found this link that seems helpful:

https://uk.indeed.com/career-advice/starting-new-job/starting-a-new-job

Comment: It is such a recurring theme on this SE that it could be a meme. Don't quit until you have another offer.

Comment: This also needs the "Don't overreact" meme.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has a bad day, sometimes. I wouldn't jump ship only because one person (not even your manager) is rude at day one. Give it some time and get a feel for the company culture.

Your team and your direct manager will be much more important to you than some HR person. Most of the people in my company don't have any contact to HR for years. Don't overthink this.

Answer (score 0):

##### Let this go

In the course of a normal job, you will hardly interact with HR at all.  What matters is how you are treated by your team,  your boss, and your customers.  HR is none of those.  I can't think of any company I have worked for where HR set the tone for a company, though at one they *thought* they did.

Further, if you quit every job where someone is rude to you, all that will happen is you spend a lot of time looking for work.